# QT desactivar QPushButton

Tags: qt

Criei um formulário com vários [QPushButtons](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html) e liguei um `SLOT` a cada um dos botões. Neste momento tenho, para cada botão, um `SLOT` diferente. Ainda que cada um dos botões desempenhe uma função diferente, parte do processamente é igual independentemente do botão. No final o botão pressionado é desactivado.

A minha questão é a seguinte: É possível criar um `SLOT` genérico que ligaria a cada um dos botões e, dentro deste, determinar qual o botão que foi pressionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível. E é mais fácil do que poderia parecer à partida. Podes usar a função [sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender)

```
void processEvent() {

    QPushButton *button_ = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());

    if (button_) {
       if (button_ == button1) {     //button1 foi pressionado

           executeSomethingB1();
       } 
       else {
          if (button_ == button2) {  //button1 foi pressionado
             executeSomethingB2();
          }
       }

       executeGenericAction();       //ação genérica
       button_->setEnabled(false);   //desactiva o botão que foi pressionado
    }
}
```

Uma nota final, não é possível usar este método quando o `SLOT` é chamado através de [Qt::DirectConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) a partir de uma thread diferente. **Não uses esta função nesse caso particular.**

Comment: Na perfeição. Valeu!